# Prevent from typing non-numbers in input in real time using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As my question says, how to prevent a user from typing non-numeric characters in the `input` field? Like e.g when they attempt to type alphabets or special characters, the cursor won't move at all inside the `input` field?

```
<input id="1stfield" name="1stfield" value="" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like following as well

```
<input type="text" class="numbersOnly" value="" />
```

for above input field, add following code in javascript..

```
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

Comment: Bad solution! This will make the cursor go to unexpected places.
Try typing with this event on - nightmare.